# Why is multiresolution asymmetric or outdated?

Tags: multiresolution

**Blender version**: 4.0.2

I want to verify how my model is playing out. This it without the **multiresolution** object modifier:

[image: Screenshot 1]

I have done the model sculpting always using the **mirror** modifier, including the **On Cage** option.

When I add **multiresolution** and subdivide the model, without applying the **mirror**, it turns asymmetric and outdated:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Attached file:

- [.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_MxqmXVT3XMmNV7JoCtaBJ6_09snlkyA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello maybe share your file?

Comment: @moonboots Added (there are two files; is .blend1 backup?)

Comment: it works fine for me if I apply the Mirror and give it a Multires, could you please share the file that you show on your second screenshot?

Comment: that saif there's a hole in your ear, you need to fix that

Comment: @moonboots Ah, so I have to apply the mirror before subdiving with multiresolution? That seemed to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put the *Multires* under the *Mirror*, so you first need to apply the *Mirror* and it will work fine. The deformed head you show is simply the head as it is if you deactivate the *Mirror* modifier (your mesh is not symmetrical, you can't see it because you use a *Mirror* modifier with the *Bisect* option, which hides the right side) .